# How to implement in app purchases in android webview app?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a Dating website where i want to create a webview android app. The website has premium features such us credits - superpowers etc.I heard that google kicks out apps that has purchase features without using their in app purchase system. Problem is that a webview app just contains the url of the website and shows it so how can i make the purchases to be made inside Google's system? Sorry for not being that clear. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? I feel like you are asking for a fully written solution which is **not** what SO is for

Comment: I haven't tried anything since i dont know if this is possible. If it is will try to figure this out